# Using tee with logger : syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, tee

Scenario 1 : Command line

```
    ./myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee >(logger -t 'MYSCRIPT')
```

Works fine and perfect : displays errors and output msg on command line 
as well as puts in the lo

Scenario 2 : Adding it to a crontab

```
    20 19 * * * imuser /home/imuser/myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee >(logger -t 'MYSCRIPT')
```

Error : syntax error near unexpected token `('

What is that I am missing here ?

Comment: how about change to `\(.....\)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cron` calls `/bin/sh`, which has a limited syntax compared to `bash`.

Try

```
20 19 * * * imuser /home/imuser/myscript.sh 2>&1 | bash -c 'tee >(logger -t MYSCRIPT)'
```

Comment: Bull's eye...! Thanks a million

Comment: @MilindVaidya You can thank me by accepting my answer.

Comment: I already tried, it asked me to wait for a minute...n then I was engrossed in testing again.....but I have done it now. Thanks again